# Rails ActiveAdmin : How to place filters on the top in index action

Tags: activeadmin

In activeadim, filters are always presented on the right side with search fields horizontally downwards. I have a requirement to place them on the top above the index table. The filters are to be presented horizontally.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: yes, its possible. You might need to dig into the source code.

Comment: Have a look at the accepted answer to this question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976604/how-to-customise-layout-components-for-activeadmin

Answer (score 1):

There's a [sidebar plugin](https://github.com/activeadmin-plugins/active_admin_sidebar) you might be able to use or modify for this.